# arm gcc toolchain as arm-elf or arm-none-eabi, what is the difference?

Tags: gcc, arm, elf, cortex-m, eabi

When you build a gcc toolchain there is the possibility to build it as  arm-elf or as arm-none-eabi, but what is the difference?

I use the eabi today, but that is just since everyone else seem to do that... but since that is a really bad argument, it would be really nice to understand the difference.

Note: This toolchain will crosscompile code for Cortex-M3 based mcu:s like the stm32.

Thanks

---

**Some links**:

EABI:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface
- http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html

ELF:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: For less deeply embedded use, look at [debian](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13798214/1163019

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Each architecture or architecture/os couple has an ABI. The ABI (Application binary Interface) describes how functions should be called, syscalls numbers, arguments passed, which registers can be used ...

The abi describes how the compiler should generate the assembly.

If you use only assembler you don't need to care about the ABI.

arm-elf and arm-none-eabi just use two versions of the Arm ABI. The eabi toolchain uses a newer revision, but could also be called arm-elf-eabi, as it generates elf too.

Answer (score 62):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410104337/https://community.freescale.com/thread/313490#comment-354077) is an excellent doc.

> Tool chains have a loose name convention like arch [-vendor] [-os] - eabi
>
> ```
>  arch -    refers to target architecture (which in our case is ARM)
>  vendor -  refers to toolchain supplier
>  os -      refers to the target operating system
>  eabi -    refers to Embedded Application Binary Interface
> ```
>
> some illustrations as follows :
>
> - **arm-none-eabi** - This tool chain targets for ARM architecture, has no vendor, does not target an operating system and complies with the ARM EABI.
> - **arm-none-linux-gnueabi** - This toolchain targets the ARM architecture, has no vendor, creates binaries that run on the Linux operating system, and uses the GNU EABI. It is used to target ARM-based Linux systems.

Comment: This post is 100% external content, though since 47 people found it helpful, the source is mentioned and the original post is dead, I don't think we should delete this answer. I have fixed the formatting to clarify that the post is just one big quote, not to be mistaken for plagiarism. I also did a rollback of grammar/spelling changes of quoted content.

Comment: What does it mean "does not target an operating system"? It still compiles to some OS-specific executable format (probably Linux), doesn't it?

Answer (score 37):

As I know:

**arm-elf** toolchain generates obj code for some OS which support executing elf format (example linux ABI). OS will control executing of your program.

**arm-none-eabi** toolchain generates obj code for micro-controllers or microprocessors (for bare metal, this will be EABI - embedded ABI). This code are downloaded to clean flash of MC and core of MC start executing it after power-on. No OS, extended command set, no possibility for linking with shared modules.

Comment: I have always been wondering how can we tell which OS the `arm-elf` toolchain is targeting **just from the name**.

Answer (score 5):

The ARM EABI is a standard created by ARM that allows different toolchains to create compatible objects. For instance, so that one toolchain can link objects created by another toolchain.