# What is the difference between arm-linux-gcc and arm-none-linux-gnueabi

Tags: gcc, arm

What is the difference between arm-linux-gcc and arm-none-linux-gnueabi and arm-linux-gnueabi
toolchains?

Do they compile differently?

Comment: Related: [Difference between arm-eabi arm-gnueabi and gnueabi-hf compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26692065/427545)

Answer (score 107):

Toolchains have a loose name convention like `arch[-vendor][-os]-abi`.

- `arch` is for architecture: **arm**, **mips**, **x86**, **i686**...
- `vendor` is tool chain supplier: **apple**,
- `os` is for operating system: **linux**, **none** (bare metal)
- `abi` is for application binary interface convention: **eabi**, **gnueabi**, **gnueabihf**

For your question, `arm-none-linux-gnueabi` and `arm-linux-gnueabi` is same thing. `arm-linux-gcc` is actually binary for gcc which produces objects for ARM architecture to be run on Linux with default configuration (abi) provided by toolchain.

Some nice reading: [Toolchains](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f12/notes/notes-toolchain.pdf).

Comment: This *might* be true, but really, there's not enough information to be sure. You need to know about the provenance of the toolchain. Non-"gnueabi" toolchains are probably quite rare, however.

Comment: Are you talking about arm-linux-gcc? or can you clarify?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that tool-chains are configured with default header and library search paths.  When cross-compiling, these should be pointing at the target image not the development machine's own headers and libraries.

Thus you can easily end up with a compiler which reports its specification as `arm-none-linux-gnueabi` that actually compile with slightly different results.

You can check this with

`gcc -print-sysroot`

Comment: @auselen: Yes, `arm-linux` seems ambiguous to me. I've not checked, and it might be that in current gcc that's a synonym, but I'll bet it's meant something different in the past. Besides, the triplet only specifies the default config, and the toolchain could have been built with other settings enabled; in that case, I would choose the generic triplet rather than have it lie.

Comment: @ams if I understand you correctly, you say arm-linux-gcc executes default settings as toolchain have been built. yes you are definitively right.

Comment: @Marko thanks for the tip. Toolchains are quite complicated as you point. I just tried to scratch the surface.

Comment: Seems the link to Toolchain is http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f12/notes/notes-toolchain.pdf