# Difference between arm-eabi, arm-elf-linux-androideabi,... when cross compiling

Tags: android, compilation, arm, cross-compiling

My final goal is to run TinyCC (TCC) on an Android Device and execute the output on the Device itself.
I know this is going to be really slow, but I need this in relation of a theoretical question in my Bachelor Thesis.

I thought of following steps to build a native TinyCC for Android(ARM):
1. Generate Standalone Toolchain with ARM Output from Android-NDK (DONE)
2. Make TinyCC a Cross-Compiler which generates ARM Output
3. Cross-Compile my cross-compiled Tcc with my Standalone Toolchain to run natively on Android

While searching for a solution for the 2. and 3. step I stumbled upon some shortcuts:
What is the difference between:
1. arm-eabi
2. arm-elf-eabi
3. arm-linux-eabi
4. arm-none-linux-eabi
5. arm-elf-linux-androideabi
6. arm-linux-androideabi?
What "do I have to Use" since I want to run the compiler and the output on ARM ?
I really do not know, which to target, what each of these really means and how to use correctly.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13798214/1163019

Comment: See: [Crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/#status).  These names are *convention*.  Anyone can assign whatever prefix they want when compiling `gcc`.  The typical tuple is *arch-vendor-os-other*.  The *other* can be a *c library*, like *android/bionic* but can include *hard float* and *gnueabi* (new *linux eabi* vs oabi).  The answer is no one knows as the compiler builder can make it whatever they like.  `auto-conf` has some rules on the names.  `gcc -dumpspecs` is more reliable.