# arm-none-eabi vs arm-eabi for cortex m3

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I am trying to write code for STM32F103. I tried downloading code sourcery compiler which installed arm-none-eabi-xxx.exe when tried to download ecos and cygwin for ecos, i ended up in getting arm-eabi-xxx.exe in cygwin folders.

I am confused among arm-none-eabi and arm-eabi.
1. Is arm-none-eabi.. and arm-eabi.. are two different set of compilers ?
2. What is the difference between these ?
3. if i compile ecos code with arm-none-eabi will i be able to run on micro controller ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797693/what-is-the-difference-between-arm-linux-gcc-and-arm-none-linux-gnueabi/13798214#13798214