# "no such file or directory" after using SCP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, scp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL Ubuntu-Bionic on my laptop and copied a file to a beaglebone (Debian-Stretch). Somehow it is shown by `ls -l` when I ssh onto the beagle, but if I try to run it, I get an error:

```
scp test debian@134.147.152.133:~/crosstest
ssh debian@134.147.152.133
ls -l 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 debian debian 8936 Jan  8 09:50 crosstest
./crosstest
-bash: ./crosstest: No such file or directory
```

Comment: typo? `ssh debian@debian@134.147.152.133`

Comment: For me the error is because of problem with the content of the file. Can you provide what is inside the script?

Comment: its a basic "hello world" cross-compiled with arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++. Trying to run this on WSL gives me `-bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Comment: @AKstat yeah, sry that was a typo in my post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around a bit, I found a solution:

As Romeo wrote, this had to have something todo with the file itself. I recompiled the file using arm-linux-gnueabi**hf**-g++ instead of arm-linux-gnueabi-g++.

I found this after reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692065/difference-between-arm-eabi-arm-gnueabi-and-gnueabi-hf-compilers)