# cross compiling for arm math

Tags: c, cross-compiling

I currently have a problem - if I write a program and in main and I use `sqrt` and for compiling I use `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc program.c -o prog-arm -lm` I have no problem (where `-lm` for linking math).

So `sqrt (25)` will print 5 at the end

But if I call another function from main for example:

```
fkt (int a) {
  int x = sqrt (a);
  return x;
}
int main () {
  int b = fkt (25);
  printf ("% d", b);
  return 0;
}
```

with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc program.c -o prog-arm -lm` 25 is output instead of 5. There is no compilation error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest ***complete*** code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it does exhibit the behaviour described.

Comment: `fkt` returns a `int` and it doesn't have a return type. Is it a typo?

Comment: There might be no compiler error but there are multiple warnings all over the place. Warnings do _not_ mean "here's a cosmetic issue you can optionally fix" but rather "here is a bug that likely prevents your program from working as intended". See [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340)

Comment: Does your program.c have `#include <math.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`? Also, the return type of `fkt` should be declared explicitly. Implicit `int` was removed in the 1999 version of the C standard.

Comment: Ah yeah missing includes could actually be the perfect explanation for this bug.

Comment: I didn't manage to provoke the error when I purposely ignored includes though, tested at gcc 11.2 arm-linux. What I was thinking is that in case includes are missing, the `sqrt` call might go bananas in case the compiler can't optimize it away, but in case it is optimized, it will just get replaced by 5.

Comment: What happens if you replace the slop code with valid standard C? That is `#include <math.h>

int fkt (int a) {
  return (int)sqrt(25);
}`.  Does the problem persist?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`
It's a bit different compiling, because of compilers underlying libraries (to the best of my knowledge). More to the topic: [Difference between arm-eabi arm-gnueabi and gnueabi-hf compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692065/difference-between-arm-eabi-arm-gnueabi-and-gnueabi-hf-compilers)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).